# Search text in ActionScript with Regex

Tags: regex, actionscript-3

I am stuck in a problem. Actually developing search functionality. I am searching pattern for example in a following string:

```
test-123,this is demo.
testing?123,this is demo.
testing!jack,thanks.
```

Above are the three lines.

What I want is as soon as I enter `test` it will search all the text (i.e all three lines) and come with result:

```
test-123
testing?123
testing!jack
```

It will search from beginning of every line till the comma character and would display the matched string. It should not truncate the special character before comma part.

Like for example

```
test
testing
testing
```

The Regular Expression which I am using and displaying the above pattern is

```
wordExp = ^wordHere\\w*
var iRegExp:RegExp = new RegExp(wordExp, "/gm");
```

It should include all the character before comma.

Please suggest the regular expression for above problem.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should change \w to [^,]*

Something like this, if your line will always start with given word:

```
^wordHere[^,]*
```

OR can be everywhere before comma :

```
^[^,]*wordHere[^,]*
```

I hope I helped

Answer (score 0):

I don't know actionscript, but this may do the job:

```
^([^,]+)
```